# How many comment votes do we each get in a day?

Tags: support, comments, votes

Today I ran out of comment votes, I did not even know this could happen.

This is not attached to my Q&A votes, I still have 10 of them left.

So I can make sure I don't waste my votes, it was annoying not to be able to vote on an important comment, how many do I get?

[image]

Comment: I *believe* it's 20, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks seth, that seems about right, I was thinking about 20 myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/203389) over on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) you get 30 comment upvotes per UTC day:

> ### Comment votes
>
> - ...
> - You get 30 comment upvotes per day.

Comment: What purpose does a limit on comment votes serve?

Comment: Just my 2 sense, I guess the purpose is to avoid irresponsible voting which will result in misleading information & to ensure we are seriously notice on what we are voted. that's it from my view.

Comment: @ElderGeek I think it is used as a method of rate limiting.

Comment: Thanks @Seth I asked that on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286775/why-is-there-a-daily-limit-on-comment-upvotes) and learned that it essentially boils down to [Everything is rate limited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32186/why-is-there-a-12-closure-per-day-maximum/32202#32202)